# Bash parallel processes have turned off the system?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, memory, c

I have a remote controlling server which I use to automatically executing commands/scripts etc to all my nodes in series. To increase the performance and speed I wanted to run it in parallel. I am executing commands approximately in 180 nodes. In series it takes me around 2 hours to finish executing in all of them. So I am looking for speed at the moment. The pseodue code looks like the following, I used based64 to send the command to other nodes. I can execute any arbitrarily complex commands using it.

```
for host in ${sshconfig[@]}; do
 ssh "$host" "echo $COMMAND | base64 -d | bash" &
done
```

But I made a mistake forgetting that there were many nodes, so my bash script created many processes for each node, as a result, the control server's system had crashed and it has turned off. Now I cannot connect to it any more.

I would like to know, how can I allocate memory in a bash script? The ease of `ssh` has made bash really ideal for my situation but I was wondering how can I improve the performance by executing them in parallel and still not to worry about system crash etc.

Comment: How many hosts are you connecting to? What does your _actual script_ look like? It's fairly easy to use `xargs` to do this in parallel in a more controlled manner. You may not allocate memory in a `bash` script (but the script you are showing does not look like `bash` at all).

Comment: @Kusalananda Updated.

Comment: are you running a cluster without a scheduler/workload & resource manager like [slurm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slurm_Workload_Manager)?  it's packaged for ubuntu as `slurm-wlm`.    If that's overkill for your needs, try `pdsh` (Parallel Distributed Shell - also packaged for ubuntu).

Comment: I was thinking, to use services like chef, ansible, puppet but not willing to pay for their services. I will try out Pdsh! I was thinking how difficult it would be to make C or C++ based Programme that can allocate memories efficiently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit the number of parallel SSH connections, you could use `xargs` like this:

```sh
printf '%s\n' "${sshconfig[@]}" |
xargs -P 4 -I {} ssh "{}" "echo $COMMAND | base64 -d | bash"
```

This would run your command in at most four parallel instances (given by `-P 4`).  The `-I {}` option would make `xargs` replace the `{}` string in the command with a string read from its standard input.  The standard input is connected to `printf` which simply prints one item from the `sshconfig` list at the time.

You would test run this with various `-P` settings until you found a number that seems to work well.

If your login shell on the remote machines is `bash`, you could also consider

```bash
code=$( base64 -d <<<"$COMMAND" )

printf '%s\n' "${sshconfig[@]}" |
xargs -P 4 -I {} ssh "{}" "$code"
```

Comment: I guess, in this case I do not require `&` anymore? I was also redirecting all my outputs `2>&1` locally, so I think with xargs I would be able to do that as well.

Comment: @RakibFiha With `xargs` you would not use `&`.  To redirect all output with `2>&1`, place that redirection _at the very end_ of the `xargs` command, or simply redirect the script itself from wherever you are running it.